# Errors using EGit in Eclipse when pushing to remote

Tags: java, eclipse, git, push, egit

I'm also trying to get help on Eclipse's forums, [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1384656/#msg_1384656), but I'll briefly explain the problem here.

I started getting errors on the second page of the push dialog (after entering or selecting the remote URI) all of a sudden, I don't know of any changed settings that would be likely to have caused it (see below). At first glance it seems like an SSH passphrase problem, see screenshot [here](http://pyraetos.net/capture.png), but having checked, regenerated (both locally and on Github, the remote server) the keys, and even switching to HTTPS instead of SSH, I'm still getting similar errors.

Now, since I've tried numerous things to fix it, the reproducibility of the individual errors is not high and I may not be able to remember the messages for all of them. It is usually an "Auth fail" or "Transport error" dialog with a short but unrevealing message, similar to the above screenshot. When I tried HTTPS, I was able to get past the second screen of the push dialog, but it ultimately failed with "cannot open git-receive-pack." The common factor here is that the stuff does not make it to the remote repo and that's unacceptable!

This is done with Windows 7, and I'm regrettably not very familiar with any command-line based solution for Linux, which I may have found on another thread on this site.

Also, like I said, this seemed to occur without a triggering setting on my part. I did perform an update in Eclipse so that I could compile Java 8-only code around the same time, but would that really cause a problem with EGit?

Anyways, thank you for helping me with this and have a great day!

Comment: Do you reproduce the issue with a fresh installation of Eclipse + Egit?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my eclipse folder and redownloaded a fresh one.

Comment: Do you get the same issue in command line? (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases)